# Buffered Input Stream does not load file correctly

Tags: java, stream, buffer, byte

I have the following code to download a List of files. After downloading I compare the md5 of the online File with the downloaded.
They are similar when the download size is lower than 1024 bytes. For all over 1024bytes, there is an different md5 sum.

Now I don't know the reason. I think, it depends on the Array-Size with 1024 bytes? Maybe it writes on every time the full 1024 bytes to the file but then the question is, why does it work with files lower than 1kb??

```
 String fileUrl= url_str;
 URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
 BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
 FileOutputStream fileOutputStream =new  FileOutputStream(target);
 BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream, 1024);

 byte data[] = new byte[1024];
 while(bufferedInputStream.read(data, 0, 1024) >0 )
 {
      bufferedOutputStream.write(data);
 }
 bufferedOutputStream.close();
 bufferedInputStream.close();
```

Comment: If you're using Java SE 7, consider to use the new Automatic Resource Management feature to close your streams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is broken:

```
while(bufferedInputStream.read(data, 0, 1024) >0 )
{
      bufferedOutputStream.write(data);
}
```

You're assuming that *every read call* fills up the entire buffer. You should use the return value of `read`:

```
int bytesRead;
while((bytesRead = bufferedInputStream.read(data, 0, 1024)) >0 )
{
    bufferedOutputStream.write(data, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

(Additionally, you should be closing all your streams in `finally` blocks, but that's another matter.)

Answer (score 1):

After the first read the data[] will be containing bytes. So during the last read the array will contain the last n bytes, and some bytes from the previous read. Actually you should check the return of the read. It indicates how many bytes has been read into the array, and write just that many bytes out.